# Anatomical separation of body components

Tags: human-anatomy

What separates the organs and parts of the body, for example, the intestine and the spine?

[image]

This image shows what makes this separation, but what would be represented in orange and yellow?

Answer (score 0):

In vertebrates at least, organs are contained within body cavities, delimited by serous membranes. Here you seem to be pointing at the limit between the abdominal body cavity (delimited by the peritoneum) and the spinal body cavity (delimited by the meninges).
Take a look at the Wikipedia page (and related links):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_cavity

Comment: I imagined it would be the peritoneum, but in the image I sent, it wasn't evident, thank you very much!